# Tkinter - editing a text box using a button

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Using Tkinter in Python I am trying to change what is displayed in a textbox when a button is pressed. My code so far is:

```
screen = Tk()
text = Text(screen, height = 2, width = 30)
text.pack()
text.insert(END, '-')

def apress():
    text.insert(END, 'a')

a = Tkinter.Button (screen, text = 'a', width = 5, command = apress).pack()

mainloop()
```

When the code is run nothing happens and the debugger will not stop running even if you click 'abort debugging'. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't there be a `StringVar` somewhere for the `Text` field.

Comment: Watch your indentation.

Comment: I added `from Tkinter import *` and removed `a = Tkinter.` and your code works for me. Linux Mint 17, Python 2.7.11.

Comment: btw: `a = Button(...).pack()` assigns `None` to `a` because `pack()` returns `None`. Use `a = Button(...) ;  a.pack()` or `Button(...).pack()` if you don't need `a`

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: no, you do not need to use a `StringVar` anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the working code:

```
from Tkinter import *

screen = Tk()
text = Text(screen, height = 2, width = 30)
text.pack()
text.insert(END, '-')

def apress():
    text.insert(END, 'a')

btn = Button(screen, text = 'a', width = 5, command = apress) 
btn.pack()

mainloop()
```

Changes I made:

- Added the import `from Tkinter import *`
- Used `Button` instead of `Tkinter.Button` - since we used an wildcard import
- `Button.pack()` separated on a new line

Demo:

Initial view:
[image: Before clicking button]

Clicked the button several times:

[image: After clicking button]

Comment: Thanks for the help! Is there anyway to replace the text on the screen when the button is pressed?

Comment: It's a little tricky - use `text.delete()` and then `text.insert()`